# The type '' cannot be used as type parameter 'T' in the generic type or method

Tags: c#, generics, lambda

I have created this generic method

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetByID<T>(IEnumerable<T> source, int id) where T : IFields
{
   return source.Where(x => x.id == id);
}
```

where the `IFieds` interface is

```
public interface IFields
{
    string code { get; set; }
    int id { get; set; }
}
```

when i try to get the value, this obviously won't compile

```
DB.GetByID(Helper.Database.Table<Items>(), 1);
```

with the following compile error.

> The type "Items" cannot be used as type parameter "T" in the generic
>   type or method
>   "DB.GetByID(System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable, int)". There
>   is no implicit reference conversion from "Items" to "IFields"

How can i fix that?
Actually, i wish to use lambda expression "in an anonymous type".

Comment: Does `Items` implement `IFields`?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Actually no sir

Comment: Then what did you expect to happen? You're specifically saying that `T` has to implement that interface and then you try to pass in a type that doesn't. I can post a simple answer that tells you why you get that error message but I suspect this isn't really going to help you. Please tell us more about why you added the constraint and why/what you expected to happen when passing in a type that doesn't implement it, perhaps we can help you do the right thing here other than just saying "Here's why that won't work".

Comment: I guess you should post it as an answer sir. I am a newbie in this stuff.
Problem solved. Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The obvious reason for this error message is that `Items` doesn't implement `IFields`.

In other words, your `Items` type need to have this:

```
public class Items : IFields
                     ^-----^
```

If you don't have this, then `Items` is not a valid type for your `GetByID<T>` method since it doesn't implement this interface.

This is true even if the `Items` type just happens to have the right members. Unless you've explicitly stated that those members also implement the interface, by doing what I showed above, then that is not enough. So even if your `Items` type have the `id` property, you still have to state explicitly that the type implements the interface.